# Use vector populated with sapply outside of the loop

Tags: r, sapply

About using populated vectors outside the loop in which they are populated:

I want to add values to my vector using the `[i]` indexing in R.

Take this example:

```
vector_for_loop = c(1:10) #take values from this vector
outcome_vector = 0 #add new values to this vector
```

I use `sapply` and add them based on the index (which is here equal to the value):

```
sapply(vector_for_loop, function(i){
  outcome_vector[i] = i+10
})
```

This prints (during the loop): `11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20`

However, I expected the `outcome_vector` to contain these values, but:

`outcome_vector` is `0`.

What am I doing wrong in populating the `outcome_vector` to have it usable after the loop?

Comment: cant u just do `vector_for_loop + 10`

Comment: You need to assign it back. i.e. `outcome_vector <- sapply(...)` but you don't need to initialize it...or use `sapply`

Comment: The *apply* family are special loops in that they return an object equal to length of input iteratively calling function on each item of input. Unlike `for` loops, do not assign or expand objects within but use whole *apply* method: `object <- sapply(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is a specific reason you want to do this using `sapply`, you could use `<<-` to assign to the parent scope:

```
vector_for_loop = c(1:10) #take values from this vector
outcome_vector = 0 #add new values to this vector

sapply(vector_for_loop, function(i){
    outcome_vector[i] <<- i+10
})
```

Using `<-` assigns `i + 10` just within the scope of the function.